# MongoDB aggregation with condition and unwind (one query instead of many)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I'd like to understand how this works:

I got collection with data like this:

```
  { _id: 5a854ee830093123a44bb7ec,
    item: 124103,
    owner: 'ZZZ',
    quantity: 50, //between 1 and X (X is fixed and I determine it before, in this case it's 50)
    lastModified: 1518685663000, //there are various lastModified intraday
    price: 116000,
    date: 2018-02-15 17:28:04.332 //default: new Date().toISOString()
  }
```

and aggregation script:

```
    x.aggregate([
        {
            $project: { year: { $year: "$date" },
                month: { $month: "$date" },
                day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" },
                item: "$item",
                owner: "$owner",
                quantity: "$quantity",
                lastModified: "$lastModified",
                price: "$price"}
        },
        {
            $match: { item: 124103, day: 15, month: 2, year: 2018, lastModified: 1518685663000}
        },
        //and here I use my group stage
        {
            $group:
               {
                   _id: "$item",
                   min_1: { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$quantity", 1] }, then: { $min: "$price" } } },
                   min_X: { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$quantity", X(50)] }, then: { $min: "$price" } } },
                 // then same for $max and $avg, (with different quantities) etc
                },
        },callback
```

What I want to receive:

in `min_X` field I'd like to receive `$min:$price` only if `quantity` is equal to X value (50).

Actually I could receive necessary data via many queries, (which I actually do right now) but I guess people in StackOverflow community knows how to achieve the same result via 1 query with $match and $unwind.

Yes, I have already read the docs, but understood only that I should your `$cond` operator. Guess someone could take me to the point up here, and provide relevant example. For example, in the future I'd like to operate with different `$lastModified` intraday, it means, I'd like to $group data after `$project` stage, then unwind cursor, and $group it with another `$lastModified`.

Comment: as for now, actually the problem is in `$match` stage, I could point there everything, that I want, for example ```$match: {item: 124103, day: 15, month: 2, year: 2018, lastModified: 1518685663000, quantity: 200}``` and then in ```$group``` stage calculate min/max/avg/whatever, the problem is how to unwind/change this ```$match``` for ```$match: {item: 124103, day: 15, month: 2, year: 2018, lastModified: 1518685663000, quantity: 1}``` and save (or export) all there data in one variable

Comment: as for now, the problem is `$project: { year: { $year: "$date" },` results with an error with the provided document, as there is no `date` field there. As a side note, it is recommended to update question itself, rather than comment on it.

Comment: there is no problem with ```$project``` at all, actual script works fine. the problem is in:  *How to receive necessary data in one query (instead of many)*

Comment: You are supposed to provide a [Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. The example you provided fails on the project stage.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry forgot to copy-paste it *before* project stage, //fixing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's other way round `$min`, then `$cond`.

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) requires one of the [accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator) for grouping fields. In your case it is `$min`. Then you can apply a condition `$cond` which value to use for aggregation. In case of `$min` you can use `Number.MAX_VALUE` for documents that don't match the criteria. It is always more or equal to any other value in javascript. You are free to use any sensible constant here.

After that you may want clean it up by replacing the junk numbers with nulls in another projection stage:

```
x.aggregate([
    .....
    { $group: {
        _id: "$item",                   
        min_1: { $min: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$quantity", 1] }, "$price", Number.MAX_VALUE ] } },
        min_50: { $min: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$quantity", 50] }, "$price", Number.MAX_VALUE ] } }
        // then same for $max and $avg, (with different quantities) etc
    } },
    { $project: {
        min_1: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$min_1", Number.MAX_VALUE] }, null, "$min_1" ] },
        min_50: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$min_50", Number.MAX_VALUE] }, null, "$min_50" ] }
    } }
])
```

Comment: btw, if I understood it correctly, I could use `$project` stage, as much as I want, right?

Comment: yep, any stage actually. As much as it makes sense.